# LWC Date input Calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a correct outcome on difference of two dates. But when I do this I am getting a result such as (ex.10211438742389) instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.. This is my JavaScript code.

```
import Division from '@salesforce/schema/User.Division';
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningExampleInputDate extends LightningElement {

    @track date1;
    @track date2;
    @track result;


    datehandler1(event) {
        this.date1 = Date.now();
        console.log(event.target.value)
    }
    datehandler2(event) {
        this.date2 = new Date(event.target.value);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
    resulthandler() {
        this.result = Math.abs(this.date2 - this.date1);
        console.log(this.result);
    }
}
```

I am expecting a shorter value to come out when I check the difference in-between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in javascripts is a representation of milliseconds starting from the [epoch date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which is 1st of Jan 1970.

If you want to calculate the difference of two dates in *days*, you could try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/1964104